# SMS Subscription SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, sms

I have a scenario I am getting the data from the backend with the customer's consent to send the SMS in real-time ( From Journey builder) but the challenge is if those customers already Opted out of that keyword then how can I opted-In them back before Sending the SMS?

Is an ampscript function available to update the status from opted out to opted in?

I know we have a Queue MO API call but running the API call for every entry will be a difficult task from the SMS activity.

Comment: You'd need to do a QueueMO or Contact update API call to achieve resubscription prior to sending the SMS

Comment: The Challenge is I only have SMS activity in the Journey where I can run this API but the message doesn't run ( if the subscriber is Opted out ) which means API doesn't run.

Comment: Hacky, but you could place a QueueMO API call in the exclusion script of an email in your journey. You'd need to provide a dummy email address in your entry data to get this to work.

Comment: Got another way, I Added the trigger API SMS code with override true in the STOP and it Optin backs the subscriber to the transactional Code.